# Time to do the "I will review"

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation, review

Assalamu 'alaikum wa rahmatu Allah wa barakatuh.

As the site grows nicely, and more questions are being asked, I think we should keep the good quality of our answers.

Personally I wrote many quick answers out of the lack of time, appending them with phrases like *"I'll research and update my answer"*, but honestly I didn't do yet.

Nevertheless, as more questions were asked we got more knowledge and became more familiar with how to answer a question and add references, more than the time when we answered many questions.

And as we try keeping an eye on the new posts to keep them at a good quality, I think we should the same thing to our old posts, probably this Aya gives the idea of what I'm trying to say:

> أَتَأْمُرُونَ النَّاسَ بِالْبِرِّ وَتَنسَوْنَ أَنفُسَكُمْ وَأَنتُمْ تَتْلُونَ الْكِتَابَ ۚ أَفَلَا تَعْقِلُونَ
>
> Muhsin Khan Translation
>
> Enjoin you Al-Birr (piety and righteousness and each and every act of obedience to Allah) on the people and you forget (to practice it) yourselves, while you recite the Scripture [the Taurat (Torah)]! Have you then no sense?
>
> [[Surat Al-Baqarah:44]](http://quran.com/2/44)

So I suggest that it's time for each of us to go to his own profile, open each of his answers (and probably questions), and see if there are any enhancements that can be done, or there is anything broken he left behind and forgot to complete.

What do you think?

Comment: As a note, you all recently did something similar to this on your [Community Self-Evaluation](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/511/islam-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical). Take a similar approach when looking at your own answers!

Comment: FYI, I generally bookmark/fave questions that I want to revisit later to answer properly, and choose not to answer at the time of.